# Why I have to wait for several minutes in order to save a render image in cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, osx

I'm using blender 3.3 on a MacBook to render an image with Cycles. When the render window appears, I have to wait several minutes while the render progresses and finishes in order to be able to save the image (The save and save as menu items are greyed out). This is annoying, becase the image in the window doesn't change at all during this time. Is there a way to avoid the waiting?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The render status will be shown in the top left corner of the window while it's rendering. The image can't be saved until that is complete. The number of Max Samples is usually set to 2048 by default in Cycles under Render Properties > Sampling > Render. Depending on the quality of the image I want, I usually set that to around 128 to speed things up.

Comment: And a bit more to the bottom is a field "time limit" where you can define how much time you will give Blender to render it. Just try 3 sec, and check whether the quality is good enough for u. If not, increase it and try again.

Comment: Thanks, for both comments. I have reduced the Max Samples from the default value of 4096 to 1 (Yes, one) and the time to complete is now just a few seconds. But the most surprising for me is that the image is identical to the one that lasted minutes to render (I compared both images visually alternating them quickly and can't find a pixel that changes).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks, for both comments. I have reduced the Max Samples from the default value of 4096 to 1 (Yes, one) and the time to complete is now just a few seconds. But the most surprising for me is that the image is identical to the one that lasted minutes to render (I compared both images visually alternating them quickly and can't find a pixel that changes).